I've been stuck here for a week now help!! How to Retrieve Mint Token Address from Transaction Signatures Using WebSocket?
I'm using a WebSocket to monitor newly launched tokens on Raydium. The code works as intended—it detects newly launches token. However, the issue is that it only provides the transaction signatures, and because of that I currently have to manually input these into Solscan to find the mint token address.
This manual process is inefficient as I need the mint token address directly to implement further logic, such as buy-and-sell operations. Is there a way to extract the mint token address directly from the transaction signatures or is it possible to retrieve the mint token address directly without the transaction signature?

Sounds like you are probably using onLogs to get the notification, and that is returning the transaction signature. You'll need to add a query when you get a transaction signature to get the transaction details (e.g., getTransaction). After you get the transaction detail, you need to parse the instruction data to identify which account is the mint.
Here's an example guide that might help you out.
